# How do consult SQL with join and where and put it in view on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, where-clause

I have:

person has many employees
employees belongs to person and has many refinancing
refinancing belongs to employee

Person has a column called cpf (uniq)
Employee has a column called register

How I do for a WHERE in view Refinancing return all registers this cpf??
I'm trying this:

```
select * from refinancings join (employees)
                               on (refinancings.employee_id = employee.id)
                               join (people)
                               on (employees.person_id = people.id)
                               where (cpf = 111111)
```

But, this return all refinancings for this cpf
I need all register this cpf. How do it?

After this I need put here:

```
 <%= f.association :employee, collection: Employee.all, label_method: :register, value_method: :id, prompt: "Select a register" %>
```

- CPF it's ok, I'm taking uby parameters in URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

SQL:

```
select * from funcionarios join (pessoas)
                           on (funcionarios.pessoa_id = pessoas.id)
                           where (cpf = '111.111.111-11')
```

Rails:

```
Funcionario.joins(:pessoa).where("pessoas.cpf" => params[:pesquisa_func_cpf])
```